# Is this subset of $GL_5(\mathbb R)$ under Vandermonde-like parametrization of square matrices path-connected?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, path-connected

Let us fix $5$ distinct nonzero real numbers $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_5\in \mathbb R$.
Let $A \in M_5(\mathbb R)$ be a $5\times 5$ matrix given by
\begin{align}
\label{eq:q}
\tag{$\star$}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_1 \lambda_1 & b_1 & b_1 \lambda_1 & b_1 \lambda_1^2 \\
a_2 & a_2 \lambda_2 & b_2 & b_2 \lambda_2 & b_2 \lambda_2^2 \\
a_3 & a_3 \lambda_3 & b_3 & b_3 \lambda_3 & b_3 \lambda_3^2 \\
a_4 & a_4 \lambda_4 & b_4 & b_4 \lambda_4 & b_4 \lambda_4^2 \\
a_5 & a_5 \lambda_5 & b_5 & b_5 \lambda_5 & b_5 \lambda_5^2 
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
where where the vectors $a=(a_1, \dots, a_5)^T$ and $b=(b_1, \dots, b_5)^T$ are linearly independent.

Let us define a set
\begin{align*}
\mathcal E = \{A \in GL_5(\mathbb R): A \text{ has form \eqref{eq:q}}\}.
\end{align*}
**Note**: By saying $A$ has form \eqref{eq:q} I mean that a matrix in $\mathcal E$ is generated by taking a linearly independent pair $(a, b)$ with the formula given by \eqref{eq:q} and meanwhile the matrix generated is nonsingular. For a linearly independent pair $a, b$, I will write $A(a,b)$ as the matrix generated by the formula in \eqref{eq:q}.

My question is: suppose we are given two linearly independent pairs $(a, b)$ and $(\hat{a}, \hat{b})$ (here I mean $a, b$ are linearly independent, $\hat{a}, \hat{b}$ are linearly independent and no assumption on the linearly independence of $a, b, \hat{a}, \hat{b}$). We assume $A(a, b), A(\hat{a}, \hat{b})$ are nonsingular. I am interested in determining whether we can connect $A(a,b)$ and $A(\hat{a}, \hat{b})$ in $\mathcal{E}$. Clearly we can connect the pairs $(a,b)$ and $(\hat{a}, \hat{b})$ with a path $\gamma$ such that the image of $\gamma$ is always a linearly independent pair (by identifying the pair by a matrix with rank $2$ and rank $2$ matrices are connected). But I am not sure how to guarantee we stay in $\mathcal E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for all choices $(\lambda_i)$ of parameters, $\mathcal E$ has at least two components.

The determinant has the form 
$$\sum \pm (\lambda_k - \lambda_l) (\lambda_n - \lambda_p) (\lambda_p - \lambda_m) (\lambda_m - \lambda_n) a_k a_l b_m b_n b_p$$
for appropriate signs $\pm$, where the sum is taken over the partitions of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ into a pair $\{k, l\}$ and a triple $\{m, n, p\}$. Since the $\lambda_i$ are distinct, all of the coefficients are nonzero. For the two pairs $(a, b_{\pm})$, $$a = (1, 1, 0, 0, 0), \quad b_{\pm} = (0, 0, \pm 1, 1, 1) ,$$ the $\det A(a, b_{\pm}) = \pm C$ for some nonzero constant. Thus, these $\mathcal E$ contains elements in both components of $GL_5(\Bbb R)$ and so cannot be connected.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But why the path will be in $\mathcal E$ by construction? I understand we can connect the two frames but how do we know the matrix generated by the two frames will in $\mathcal E$ by the prescribed formula in $\star$?

Comment: By definition $\mathcal{E}$ contains $A(a, b) \in \mathcal E$ for all $2$-frames $(a, b)$ of $\Bbb R^5$. In particular it contains all points $(a(t), b(t))$ on the path.

Comment: I might not have presented my question in a clear way. I defined $\mathcal E$ to be a subset of general linear maps and also the elements satisfy the formula prescribed by $\star$ relation.

Comment: Oh, I see, when you define $\mathcal E$ you imposing the condition that $A(a, b)$ be nondegenerate.

Comment: Yes. Is your answer applicable with some change?

Comment: No, because the answer is the opposite and for a simpler reason. We can choose the $\lambda_a$ such that $\det A(a, b)$ is positive for some $(a, b)$ and negative for some other choice. Thus $\mathcal E$ has elements in both of the connected components of $GL(5, \Bbb R)$ and so has (at least) two components.

Comment: I see thanks. But could we prove it has precisely two components?

Comment: You're welcome. And I'm not sure how many components $\mathcal E$ has. Once we fix $\lambda_a$, we can identify $\mathcal E$ with a copy of $\Bbb R^{5 + 5} = \Bbb R^{10}$ with the real variety $\{(a, b) : A(A, b) = 0\}$ removed. But this variety is generically complicated: It's defined by the vanishing of a single (quintic) polynomial in $(a_1, \ldots, b_5)$ and so has dimension $9$ at smooth points. I'd speculate that the number of components depends on the choice of $\lambda_a$.

Comment: I've replaced my answer with a more detailed explanation of my third comment above.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask how you get the determinant formula? I mean is there some trick to get it quickly?

Comment: You're welcome. Cofactor expansion along the first two columns and collecting terms appropriately gives a sum of terms $a_k a_l \det\pmatrix{1& \lambda_k \\ 1 & \lambda l} \det\pmatrix{b_m & b_m \lambda_m & b_m \lambda_m^2 \\ b_n & b_n \lambda_n & b_n \lambda_n^2 \\ b_p & b_p \lambda_p & b_p \lambda_p^2}$. Pulling out the factors $b_m, b_n, b_p$ from the respective rows leaves that the determinant of the $3 \times 3$ matrix is $b_m b_n b_p \det \pmatrix{1 & \lambda_m & \lambda_m^2 \\ 1 & \lambda_n & \lambda_n^2 \\ 1 & \lambda_p & \lambda_p^2}$.

Comment: ...but both the $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ matrices are Vandermonde matrices, so the determinants are (for an appropriate order) the products of the differences of the parameters---so $(\lambda_n - \lambda_p) (\lambda_p - \lambda_m) (\lambda_m - \lambda_p)$ for the $3 \times 3$ matrix.