# Does this subset of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ under Vandermonde-like parametrization have precisely two path-connected components?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, path-connected

Let us fix $2$ distinct nonzero real numbers $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2\in \mathbb R$.
Let $A \in M_2(\mathbb R)$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix given by
\begin{align}
\label{eq:q}
\tag{$\star$}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_1 \lambda_1  \\
a_2 & a_2 \lambda_2 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Let us define a set
\begin{align*}
\mathcal E = \{A \in GL_2(\mathbb R): A \text{ has form \eqref{eq:q}}\}.
\end{align*}

I am interested on the number of path-connected components in $\mathcal E$. Is it four or two? It should be at least $2$ since $(1,1)$ would give positive determinant and $(-1, 1)$ would give negative determinant. It is also clear if $(a_1, a_2)$ and $(b_1, b_2)$ have same sign in each coordinate, i.e., $\text{sign}(a_i) = \text{sign}(b_i)$, we could obviously use a straight line to connect them. But does this mean it has $4$ connected components determined by all the combinations of signs?

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970993/is-this-subset-of-gl-5-mathbb-r-under-vandermonde-like-parametrization-of-sq

Comment: I asked that question. This is a simpler one but different.

Comment: Yes, I know, I answered it. :) I was just linking it there for context for anyone else interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are precisely four components.

**Hint** The determinant of the matrix is $$\det A = a_1 a_2 (\lambda_2 - \lambda_1) ,$$ which vanishes iff $a_1 = 0$ or $a_2 = 0$.